# What does +-# after percent of cache misses mean in perf stat?

Tags: caching, perf

I used `perf stat  --repeat 100 -e cache-references,cache- misses,cycles,instructions,branches,faults,migrations ./avx2ADD` command and the output is followed. What does `+-  8.93%` for `cache-misses` mean when percent of cache misses is equal to `4.010 %`?

```
 32,425      cache-references                                       ( +-  0.54% )
  1,300      cache-misses         #    4.010 % of all cache refs    ( +-  8.93% )
538,839      cycles                                                 ( +-  0.28% )
520,056      instructions         #    0.97  insns per cycle        ( +-  0.22% )
 98,720      branches                                               ( +-  0.20% )
     95      faults                                                 ( +-  0.12% )
      0      migrations                                             ( +- 70.35% )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+-  8.93%` part is described in manual page:

> **-r, --repeat=**
>
> repeat command and print **average** + **stddev** (max: 100). 0 means forever.

If you are not sure what is meant be abbreviation of `stddev`, it it [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) (yes, also there could be manual page more verbose). In short, how much the results differ from all the repeated measurements. Less value is better, but if you have such a small problem (500k instructions), deviation will be larger, because cache-misses might be non-deterministic.

The percentage `4.010 %` then means the *average* from the description above.

Comment: What about the number of faults?

Comment: I don't have this event on my CPU for some reason. But is the same logic. Average is 95 faults and the stddev is 0.12% (quite regular).

Comment: Does it rely on aliasing problem in cache?

Comment: No. AVX requires the vectors aligned. If you use inrinsics directly, it would segfault for wrong aligned data, AFAIK.

Comment: It's aligned to 32 byte.

Comment: When a program generates an access request to a 
page that is not in the main memory, a page fault is 
said to have occurred.  The whole page must be 
brought from the disk into the memory before access 
can proceed
Processing of the active task is 
interrupted, and control is transferred to the 
operating system. The operating system then copies 
the requested page from the disk into the main 
memory and returns control to the interrupt task. From [here](http://www.ee.ncu.edu.tw/~jfli/computer/lecture/ch06.pdf)